# log python module imported for statistics

Tags: python, python-2.x

I maintained a nfs server holding python2.7 installation when most of my colleagues' desktops have python2.6 bundle. It is shared to users so they have a different python version. Although more and more users switched to anaconda and have their environment, this central python2.7 is still needed for some time.

As the modules/packages are getting more and more, the version conflicts also get more. I would like to 'reinstall' this huge central python2.7 but don't want to add back some 'cold' packages which users are no longer using.

Is there some method I could get the information that, what packages/modules are still being used? So that I will only install them (and some other still hot packages and dependencies).

My users have this settings:

```
/mountpath/to/apps/bin/python2.7
/mountpath/to/apps/lib/python2.7/site-packages/*
```

Is it possible to just modify some start script (python rc, or `/mountpoint/to/apps/bin/python2.7` wrapper script) and logs the modules users are using for the rest of the sessions, without disturbing the users ?

Comment: Could you list those directories by `atime` and lose the ones that are before a cutoff date? For me on macOS (BSD) it's `$ ls -luT` to display the last time the file was accessed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, this is the output of ls -lut
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root      87 May 13 00:29 zxcvbn_python-4.4.15.dist-info
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root    4096 May 13 00:29 zxcvbn
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root     136 May 13 00:29 zope.interface-4.5.0.dist-info
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root     161 May 13 00:29 zope.deprecation-4.3.0.dist-info
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root      87 May 13 00:29 zodbpickle-1.0.1.dist-info
drwxr-xr-x.  4 root root      42 May 13 00:29 zope
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root root    4096 May 13 00:29 zodbpickle

,,,
maybe it is my nightly backup access,,,